# How to alter next sequence number with last increment value using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, sequence

I want to alter next sequence number after for each loop.How can i get the last incremented number using PHP?

$incjobid = $job_Id++;//1,2,3,4 and i need to alter the next sequence number with 5.
At a time am inserting 4 records with id 1,2,3,4 and it should be next sequence number should be 5.How to set this?

```
$this->db->select('NEXT VALUE FOR job_seq as jobid');
$queryjobid = $this->db->get();                     
foreach ($queryjobid->result_array() as $row) {
    $job_Id = $row['jobid'];
}


   if (is_array($this->input->post('getschedule'))) {
                foreach($this->input->post('getschedule') as $value) {

                    //Auto generate JOB SCHEDULE HERE
                    $this->db->insert('job_schedule', array(
                        'jobschedule_id' => $jobschedule_id,
                        'Activity_area_id' => $Activity_area_id,
                        'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
                        'job_freq_id' => $this->input->post('getcontractbranch_freq'),
                        'job_schedule_dates' => $value[0], //assume array form like your screenshot
                        'job_schedule_frequency' => $value[1],
                        'created_at' =>$created_Dt
                    ));


                    //Auto generate JOB HERE
                    $incjobid = $job_Id++;
                    $this->db->insert('job', array(
                        'Job_id' => $incjobid,
                        'Job_no' => $incjobid,
                        'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
                        'Job_Date' => $value[0],
                        'Start_time' => '08:30',
                        'Activity_Area_id' => $Activity_area_id,
                        'created_Dt' => $created_Dt,
                        'status' => 'open',
                        'sr_available' => '0'
                        //'end_time' => $this->input->post('getEnd_Time') ?: null,
                        //'team_id' => $this->input->post('getassignedtoJob'),
                        //'type_of_services_id' => $this->input->post('gettypeofserviceJob'),
                        //'type_of_visit_id' => $this->input->post('gettypeofvisitjob')
                    ));
                }


                $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id(); 
                //$this->db->ALTER('SEQUENCE job_seq RESTART WITH 547');
                    //$queryjobalter = $this->db->get();
                    //$queryjobalter->result();

            }
```

Comment: Can anyone plz help to do this?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya am using NEXT sequence number know

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya now the problem is next sequence value is wrong.sowhen i am doing next transaction it showing duplicate ID..(means already id is exits in the table)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya so i want to do after stoped increment value plus 1 i need to set with next sequence value

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya am inserting into two different table..i need to update the sequence  name job_seq value with last increment value eg $incjobid = $job_Id++; (1,2,3,4) and update with 5 next sequence value

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Please help me to do this sir?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Now the problem is when i insert 4 records at first time, sequence is incremeting by 1 and next sequence value will show 2.Instead of that i need to show 5.Then only when i insert next record it will insert like 5,6,7 etc

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Is there any solution for this?or am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont have any idea of `FOR NEXT VAL` syntax. This seems like Oracle question. You may need to add more relevant tags to the question, so that larger community may show interest.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya am using sql server 2014

Comment: Why is the post tagged with oracle?!

Comment: You know that it is possible to make auto increment field in your table? Without any magic in php?